# Unable to connect to a dockerized database. I am getting hostname resolving error when I try to connect from golang server, what should be done?

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, docker-compose, go-gorm

So I have a `docker-compose.yaml`

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: test
    networks: [ "test_network" ]

  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_USER: user
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      DB_NAME: test
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks: [ "test_network" ]

networks:
   test_network:
        driver: bridge
```

In my golang application code, I try to connect to db like this,

```
db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.New(postgres.Config{
        DSN:                  "host=db user=user password=password dbname=test port=5432",
        PreferSimpleProtocol: true, // disables implicit prepared statement usage
    }), &gorm.Config{})
```

When I do `docker-compose up`, it fails with,

```
[error] failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to `host=postgres user=user database=test`: hostname resolving error (lookup postgres on 127.0.0.11:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:36942->127.0.0.11:53: i/o timeout)
news-api-app-1  | 2023/04/08 07:16:38 Cannot run server, encountered an error whilst initializing - failed to connect to `host=postgres user=user database=test`: hostname resolving error (lookup postgres on 127.0.0.11:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:36942->127.0.0.11:53: i/o timeout)
```

For starters, why is it connecting to `host=postgres` when I explicitly mentioned in application code that `host=db`? And why is it failing?

From `psql` I am able to connect to the database.
What should be done to fix this?

Comment: Since you have environment variables such as `DB_HOST` in the `docker-compose.yaml` file, I would assume that the connection string is constructed from the environment variables instead of hard-coding as what you show. And maybe there is a typo in the code that constructs the connection string.

Comment: I had to do a rebuild. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Oh so the issue was that I had changed the host but didn't do a rebuild, rebuilding solved the problem.